# php mysql function with optional parameter

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with giving optional parameters for php function which will search in MySQL database for the matching criteria.

Scenario: Front-end =
There will be 6 html input form field named as authorName, authorCountry, authorState and so on

When user fills this fields, field values will be passed as a mysql parameters for searching db. Here the problem is, if user wants to know the list of authors in USA, he will enter USA in country field and leave other fields. But this will break the mysql query since other fields are left blank.

i tried doing but it dint work for me.

```
function getAuth(authName=NULL, authCoun=NULL, authSate=NULL) {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM authTable WHERE authName='authName'
AND authCoun='authCoun' AND authSate='authSate'");
return $query; }
```

Please help me to pass optional parameter.

Thank you..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function getAuth($authName=NULL, $authCoun=NULL, $authSate=NULL) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM authTable WHERE 1 = 1";
    if ($authName) {
        $sql .= " AND authName='$authName'";
    }
     if ($authCoun) {
        $sql .= " AND authCoun='$authCoun'";
    }
     if ($authSate) {
        $sql .= " AND authSate='$authSate'";
    }
    return mysql_query($sql);
 }
```

And make sure you have these variable escaped before passing to the function.

Answer (score 5):

Do it this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM authTable 
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND (@authName IS NULL OR authName = @authNameParam)
  AND (@authCoun IS NULL OR authCoun = @authCounParam)
  AND (@authSate IS NULL OR authSate = @authSateParam)
 ...
```

This query won't break even if no parameters at all passed to this query, i.e passed all with `NULL` value in this case the whole `WHERE` clause will become `WHERE 1 = 1` which will acts like `SELECT * FROM authtable` as if there were no `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Do we really need `1 = 1`? Looks like it should work without this condition.

Answer (score 0):

the function should be like this

```
function getAuth(authName=NULL, authCoun="Default value", authSate="Default value") {}
```

when you don't pass value to function default values are coming.